# Assigning names to 12 monthly data frames in a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a data in excel where each tab has data corresponding to 12 different months in a year.

I import the data by using the following function

```
read_excel_allsheets <- function(filename) {
sheets <- readxl::excel_sheets(filename)
x <- lapply(sheets, function(X) readxl::read_excel(filename, sheet = X))
names(x) <- sheets
x
}

mysheet <- read_excel_allsheets("Delayed_11_12.xlsx")
```

mysheet is a list where each component corresponds to the monthly dataset.
The Monthly data set has the following variables or columns suppose "Code", "x1", "x2", "x3", "x4".

What I basically would like to do is to paste the name of the month to the columns except for the first one which is Code for each of the above monthly data so for example for April monthly data it is "Code", "x1_April", "x2_April", "x3_April", "x4_April" and so on for other months. And then finally save all the monthly data into one data frame.

I have tried loops, nested loops etc. but to no avail. Can you please help to sort it out?

Thank you

Comment: You did not include the sheet names. Are the month indicators in the name? And if so, what is the format?

Comment: The sheet names are as follows April_11 to March_12 that is from the months April to March

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this also by using a combination of the `dcast` and `rbindlist` functions from the `data.table`-package. With the data of @TobiasDekker:

```
library(data.table)
dcast(rbindlist(mysheet, idcol = 'month'), 
      Code ~ month, 
      value.var = c('x_1','x_2','x_3'))
```

which gives:

```
   Code x_1_April_12 x_1_May_12 x_2_April_12 x_2_May_12 x_3_April_12 x_3_May_12
1:    1            a          a            a          a            a          a
2:    2            b          b            b          b            b          b
3:    3            c          c            c          c            c          c
4:    4            d          d            d          d            d          d
5:    5            e          e            e          e            e          e
```

However, in my opinion it is better to keep your data in long format. If you want to do that, you only need `rbindlist`:

```
rbindlist(mysheet, idcol = 'month')
```

which gives:

```
       month Code x_1 x_2 x_3
 1: April_12    1   a   a   a
 2: April_12    2   b   b   b
 3: April_12    3   c   c   c
 4: April_12    4   d   d   d
 5: April_12    5   e   e   e
 6:   May_12    1   a   a   a
 7:   May_12    2   b   b   b
 8:   May_12    3   c   c   c
 9:   May_12    4   d   d   d
10:   May_12    5   e   e   e
```

Answer (score 1):

It was a bit guessing how your input exactly looks like but I made the following example and solution:

```
mysheet <- list(April_12 = data.frame(Code = 1:5, x_1 = c("a", "b", "c","d", "e"), x_2 = c("a", "b", "c","d", "e"), x_3 = c("a", "b", "c","d", "e")),
                May_12 =  data.frame(Code = 1:5, x_1 = c("a", "b", "c","d", "e"), x_2 = c("a", "b", "c","d", "e"), x_3 = c("a", "b", "c","d", "e")))

> mysheet
$April_12
  Code x_1 x_2 x_3
1    1   a   a   a
2    2   b   b   b
3    3   c   c   c
4    4   d   d   d
5    5   e   e   e

$May_12
  Code x_1 x_2 x_3
1    1   a   a   a
2    2   b   b   b
3    3   c   c   c
4    4   d   d   d
5    5   e   e   e

lapply(names(mysheet), function(x) colnames(mysheet[[x]])[2:ncol(mysheet[[x]])] <<- paste(colnames(mysheet[[x]])[2:ncol(mysheet[[x]])], x, sep = "_"))
names(mysheet) <- NULL
output  <- do.call(cbind, mysheet)
output <- output[colnames(output)[!duplicated(colnames(output))]]

> output
  Code x_1_April_12 x_2_April_12 x_3_April_12 x_1_May_12 x_2_May_12 x_3_May_12
1    1            a            a            a          a          a          a
2    2            b            b            b          b          b          b
3    3            c            c            c          c          c          c
4    4            d            d            d          d          d          d
5    5            e            e            e          e          e          e
```

- Step 1: First change the col names with pasting the month name to the colnames except the code colname
- Step 2: Make the names of the list NULL such that cbind does not paste the names to the columns
- Step 3: cbind the list
- Step 4: Delete the duplicated code columns